# Interrogative very detailed

Tags: interrogatives

First of all when you search how to form a question, in english in every grammar site it is written: subject verb inversion and wh forms and possible do forms.

WH forms are listed as interrogative pronouns;

However no one underlines these types of questions;

**Whose** book is this?
**Which** pen will they give us?
**What** CD Sarah likes most?

I guessed they can refer as interrogative adjectives and searched it on Google.Thus found some resources that are belonging to foreign sites that are built to teach English to whom that are not natives.

In Cambridge Dictionary sites the examples I gave considered as using wh forms as noun heads.

Furthermore I have found that there are also interrogative adverbs!
**How** cool is that?

So anyone can explain about this unofficial dilemma?

Ps:To cut it short I have listed like that are they correct?

```
1.What do you do? What is interrogative pronoun

2.What Cd does Sarah like? ..........  adjective

3.How cool is that? ................ adverb
```

Comment: references:grammarmonstericambridge,teachingbanyan,efl,englishcouncil

Comment: See [**this link**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/questions-interrogative-pronouns-what-who) and [**this link.**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/how?q=How)  What is your dilemma? _What, which,_ and _whose_ are interrogative pronouns. _How_ is an adverb.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I guess _which_ and _what_ can also be interrogative adjectives. Am I write? Perhaps he is asking "how to distinguish them".

Comment: @Ganesh.R Very astute! Yes, _what_ and _which_ can act as both.

Answer (score 1):

In English, *interrogative pronouns* are used when we ask questions. They are:

> • who   • which   • whom   • what   • whose

We also have words called *interrogative adjectives* that we use in questions, and among them are:

> • what   • which   • whose

The question obviously arises: "How can I tell the difference?"

### Interrogative Adjectives

An *interrogative adjective,* like any adjective, modifies and precedes a noun. When you encounter *what, which,* or *whose* in a sentence, first ask the question: "Does it modify a noun?" The answer will tell you whether the word is acting as an *interrogative adjective* or *interrogative pronoun.* If the word modifies a noun, it's an interrogative adjective. If it can stand alone, it's an interrogative pronoun.

Below, *which* is an *interrogative adjective* that modifies the noun "CD."

> **Which** CD does Sarah like?

### Interrogative Pronouns

An *interrogative pronoun,* like any pronoun, can stand on its own. When you see  *what, which,* or *whose* in a question and you're not sure whether or not it's an *interrogative pronoun,* try forming the sentence as a declarative; if the word serves as an object in the declarative form, it's an *interrogative pronoun.* For example:

> **Whose** is the orange cat?

The declarative form of this sentence is:

> The orange cat is **whose.**

We know that **whose** is an *interrogative pronoun* in the original sentence because it serves as a direct object in the declarative sentence.

Here are some more example sentences:

> **Whose** book is this?    ☜ *whose* modifies *book;* Interrogative adjective
>   **Which** does Sarah like?    ☜ *which* is the object of *like;* Interrogative pronoun
>   **What** CD does Sarah like most?    ☜ *what* modifies *CD;* Interrogative adjective
>   **What** are you up to?    ☜ *what* is the object of the prepositional phrase *up to;* Interrogative pronoun.

Comment: Hmm, there are several good points here. BTW, First, I often confuse the conjunction "where" with pronouns. Second, I think you could mention the subject role of those pronouns in interrogative questions like "Whose are these books."

Comment: @Cardinal I'm glad you find it useful. Hopefully, the OP will also find some value in it. It's hard to tell! ("Whose are these books" is a plural form of my example sentence above. In "Whose are these books," the subject is _books,_ not _whose._ The declarative form is _These books are whose,_ and _whose_ is an _interrogative adjective._)

Comment: @ P.E. Dant ,So what about how?

Comment: As I understand How can be classified as only an interrogative adverb.[link](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/interrogative-adverbs/)

Comment: Finally I listed them; **Inter. Pronoun** :   • who   • which   • whom   • what   • whose; **Inter. Adjective** :Whose, What, Which; **Inter. Adverb** :Why, Where,When, How

Comment: @aintnosunshinewhenyouaregone Yes, those are the adverbs used as _interrogative adverbs._ I don't discuss them in the answer because they cause no confusion; none of them can serve in two capacities as can _what,  which_ and _whose._

Comment: @aintnosunshinewhenyouaregone It's not correct to say that "How can be classified as only an interrogative adverb." _How_ is an adverb, and sometimes acts as an interrogative adverb, but it has other uses as well. Webster's Collegiate has: **note: _how_ is used in each sense, interrogatively, interjectionally, and relatively; it is also often employed to emphasize an interrogation or exclamation. "how are the mighty fallen!" i. 27. sometimes, also, it is used as a noun; -- as, the how, the when, the wherefore. let me beg you -- don't say "how?" for "what?"**